# Define a matrix in R and pass it to C++

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a matrix defined in R. I need to pass this matrix to a c++ function and do operations in C++. 
Example: In R, define a matrix,

```
A <- matrix(c(9,3,1,6),2,2,byrow=T)
PROTECT( A = AS_NUMERIC(A) );
double* p_A = NUMERIC_POINTER(A);
```

I need to pass this matrix to a C++ function where variable 'data' of type `vector<vector<double>>` will be initialized with the matrix A.

I couldn't seem to figure out how to do this. I am thinking in more complicated way then I should be, I bet there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: It is pretty stupid to store matrices as `vector<vector<double>>`; for sake of questionably better readability you risk memory fragmentation and breaking of the alignment optimisation. Moreover, this way you copy data which is already present in memory and ready to use -- this is a significant overhead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Paul said, I would recommend using [`Rcpp`](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) for that kind of things. But it also depends what you want your `vector< vector<double> >` to mean. Assuming you want to store columns, you might process your matrix like this:

```
require(Rcpp)
require(inline)

fx <- cxxfunction( signature( x_ = "matrix" ), '
    NumericMatrix x(x_) ;
    int nr = x.nrow(), nc = x.ncol() ;
    std::vector< std::vector<double> > vec( nc ) ;
    for( int i=0; i<nc; i++){
        NumericMatrix::Column col = x(_,i) ;
        vec[i].assign( col.begin() , col.end() ) ;
    }
    // now do whatever with it
    // for show here is how Rcpp::wrap can wrap vector<vector<> >
    // back to R as a list of numeric vectors
    return wrap( vec ) ;
', plugin = "Rcpp" )
fx( A )
# [[1]]
# [1] 9 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 3 6
```

Comment: We also have numerous examples in the Rcpp documentation, and assorted blog posts. If you can be more specific about *what it is* you actually want to do with your matrix, we can provide more help.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to use Rcpp. This package allows easy integration of R and C++, including passing objects from R to C++. The package is available on CRAN. In addition, a number of packages on CRAN use Rcpp, so they could serve as inspiration. The website of Rcpp is here:

http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html

which includes a few tutorials.

Comment: you've been quicker. I'll reply too with some meat.

Comment: Thanks, that would be helpful for the OP