# C++ and R interface, getting output

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I just started learning R, thus getting stuck with trivial looking issues. I am trying to figure out how values are outputted in R. In C++ we simply use return variable, but that doesn't seem to be the case with R. Say I have a function that takes 4 input arguments, passes those arguments to a c++ function which does the required calculations, now if I want to load this myfun in R and get output from the c++ funciton, what do I need to do? Following is the template I am trying to use.

```
extern "C" {
   SEXP myfun(SEXP S, SEXP A, SEXP B, SEXP C) { //will call this function from R.
     SEXP rate, dir, list, list_names; //declare variables

     PROTECT( rate = allocMatrix(REALSXP, 10, 2) ); //allocate 10x2 matrix of double type?
     PROTECT( dir = allocVector(INTSXP, 10) ); //allocated vector(10) of int type?

     double* p_rate = REAL(rate); //why do I need pointers? 
     int* p_dir = INTEGER(dir);
```

//here I call a C++ function which calculates `vector<vector<double> > someVal` and `vector<int> someVal2`.

Now I want to pass those values to the rate and dir.

```
 for(int i =0; i < 10; i++){
      rate[i][0] = someVal1[i][0];
      rate[i][1] = someVal1[i][1];
      dir[i] = someVal2[i]; 
  }
```

but the compiler doesn't like it. I am not sure how to use the p_rate and p_dir pointers in this case.

Also, I am not quite understand why the following code is the way it is. It seems to be passing the strings, rate and dir to the list_names and values to the rate and dir. Why can't we simply do cout and print the desired values?

```
   char *tag[2] = {"rate","dir"};
   PROTECT(list_names = allocVector(STRSXP ,2));
   SET_STRING_ELT(list_names, 0, mkChar(tag[0]));
   SET_STRING_ELT(list_names, 1, mkChar(tag[1]));
   PROTECT(list = allocVector(VECSXP ,2));
   SET_VECTOR_ELT(list, 0, rate);
   SET_VECTOR_ELT(list, 1, dir);
   setAttrib(list, R_NamesSymbol , list_names);

   UNPROTECT(8);
   return (list);
}
```

I am not getting the basic idea behind returning the variables in R, it seems very confusing. I would really appreciate if someone could point me to the appropriate resources that explains these stuffs.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 9):

If you are already familiar with C++, you may find our [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) project for seamless R and C++ integrarion useful.  It contains *a lot* of documentation and examples, plus CRAN has now over 80 packages using it which provides another large corpus of examples.

You could start with "Introduction" vignette which corresponds to our [JSS paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i08), and also peruse the `[rcpp]` tag here.

Otherwise, you are back at the R API which is more bare-bones and based on C only.

Answer (score 5):

As we said while answering your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324664/define-a-matrix-in-r-and-pass-it-to-c), give [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) a shot, and take away all the kludge in your code.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

void yourCode( std::vector< std::vector<double> >& someVal, 
               std::vector<double>& someVal2 ){ ... }

extern "C" SEXP myfun() { 
    NumericMatrix rate(10, 2); 
    NumericVector dir(10) ;

    std::vector< std::vector<double> > someVal ;
    std::vector< double > someVal2 ;

    // call whatever function that fills someVal and someVal2
    yourCode( someVal, someVal2 ) ;

    // fills rate and dir
    for(int i =0; i < 10; i++){
      rate(i, 0) = someVal1[i][0];
      rate(i, 1) = someVal1[i][1];
      dir[i] = someVal2[i]; 
    }

    // structure the output
    List result = List::create( 
        _["rate"] = rate,
        _["dir"] = dir
    ) ;

    return result ;

}
```